# Doing a join after a select MYSQL

Tags: mysql, select

I'm wondering if its possible to do a join after a select or query. This is the starting query:

```
    SELECT * 
      FROM citas 
INNER JOIN cita_solicituds 
        ON citas.id=cita_solicituds.cita_id 
INNER JOIN users 
        ON citas.user_id = users.id
```

As you can see I'm doing two joins, the base table is `citas` and gets join to `cita_solicituds` and users. This is retrieving the results perfectly. But, after I get this results I want to do another join but with a table that has no relation to `citas`. It will kinda look like:

```
   (SELECT * 
      FROM citas 
INNER JOIN cita_solicituds 
        ON citas.id=cita_solicituds.cita_id 
INNER JOIN users 
        ON citas.user_id = users.id) 
INNER JOIN horario 
        ON (RESULT JUST FETCHED).horario_id = horario.id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT * 
  FROM citas 
  INNER JOIN cita_solicituds ON citas.id=cita_solicituds.cita_id 
  INNER JOIN users ON citas.user_id = users.id) q 
INNER JOIN horario ON q.horario_id = horario.id
```

I supossed that you have a field `horario_id` in `citas`, `cita_solicituds` or `users`.

Answer (score 0):

It can be like :

```
SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT * 
  FROM citas 
  INNER JOIN cita_solicituds ON citas.id=cita_solicituds.cita_id 
  INNER JOIN users ON citas.user_id = users.id) q, horario h
where q.horario_id = h.horario.id
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem to join seveal tables, an you do not need to group them, MySQL will understand the optimal order itself:

```
SELECT * 
FROM citas 
INNER JOIN cita_solicituds 
  ON citas.id=cita_solicituds.cita_id 
INNER JOIN users 
  ON citas.user_id = users.id
INNER JOIN horario
  -- not sure if horario_id comes from users or cita_solicituds 
  ON users.horario_id = horario.id
```